# React Router 2.0 check if route exists

Tags: react-router

I have a link that may or may not be configured as a route in redux-router.

Is it possible to ask the router if the URL would match? Without actually routing there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `router.match(path)`. You can get the router instance from context (like `Link` does) or as the return value of `Router.run` or `Router.create` and then pass it via props or globals.

Comment: It seems like the `router` object doesn't have a `match` function.  But there is a `match` function on the root object of `react-router` which seems to be somewhat fit for the task: 
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/fb192a707a84d0ae65a3afe0e2f2900e94a5fc9e/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md#server-rendering